# Add an extra column with header to a csv using awk

Tags: bash, sh

I am trying to add an extra column (i.e 11th column in my CSV) with header to an existing CSV.

I'm using the following command, I was able to add extra column but unable to put the header name.

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {$11="\"PRD\""; print}' existingfile.csv > newfile.csv
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add sample input with expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header, I assume, is the first line of the file, so you can just test for that:

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } NR==1{$11="Header";print; next}{$11="\"PRD\""; print}' existingfile.csv > newfile.csv
```